# JSON class in C# and retrieve ID tag

Tags: c#, json

I made JSON class from the JSON file (This JSON file is in web browser).
JSON class is complicated for me and I don't know how can I retrieve the ID by having this class. How can I use for it (C#). or must i change the format of my class? because I could not see anything about ID in class?(BTW: http://json2csharp.com/ is used to generate the class)

JSON data:

```
"context_id": "311",
      "field_names": [
        **"ID"**,
        "name",
        "hash",
        "score",
        "rank"
      ],
      "field_values": [
        [
          "18",
          "18",
          "18",
          "12",
          "9.7"
        ],
          .......
```

The class:

```
public class zzz
{
    public string context_id { get; set; }
    public List<string> field_names { get; set; }
    public List<List<string>> field_values { get; set; }
    public int total { get; set; }
    public string version { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "class" seems to be organized like a table with column names in one field and an array of rows in another. Based on your class it looks like you could do:

```
int idxID = field_names.IndexOf("ID");
List<string> values = field_values.Select(v => v[idxID])
                                  .ToList();  // select that value from each list
```

or in one line:

```
List<string> ids = field_values.Select(v => v[field_names.IndexOf("ID")])
                               .ToList();  // select that value from each list
```